# convert month/day/year/time to timeval in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, time, timeval

In C/C++, suppose I have the following values:

```
int year = 2010;
int month = 6;
int day = 15;
int hour = 14;
int minute = 52;
int seconds = 34;
int microseconds = 141231;
```

What's the easiest way to convert this to a timeval? I think timeval is time since Jan 1, 1970? But to calculate this manually everytime seems very tedious. What's the easiest (and fastest) way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`mktime(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime) to convert a `struct tm` structure into a `time_t`.  After you have the `time_t`, you can copy it and your microseconds value directly into a [`struct timeval`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday) structure.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look into [`std::mktime()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime).

Comment: `std::mktime()` normally neither takes nor produces anything with microseconds, see original post.